# How do I get a SQL function to return a list to be used by the IN statement in a WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, where-clause

I have a complex SQL Query, that needs to be filtered further. Part of the WHERE clause looks like this:

```
Where P.PeriodID in (36, 37)
```

I need to get it to look more like this:

```
Where P.PeriodID in dbo.GetPeriodsInRange(@startDate, @endDate)
```

The function must return a list of PeriodIDs to be used by the IN statement. I really suck at writing functions, so I need some assistance. Also, I'm not sure how to deal with edge cases, say if there are no periods in the specified date range.

The function above doesn't need to get evaluated for each row. It will be the same for each row, so there is probably some optimisation that can be done, maybe before the query is executed.

I'm pretty sure I'm breaking several "best practices" here, so please point them out to me if there is a better way to do this. However, performance is not an issue, so I'm willing to sacrifice performance in favour of simplicity.

My question applies to T-SQL (MS SQL Server 2000/2005)

Comment: How about: WHERE P.PeriodID IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.GetPeriodsInRange(@startDate, @endDate))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be to create a function as Mudu suggested. I  m using [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/integer-table.aspx).

From the link:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GenerateIntegers] ( @MinValue INT, @MaxValue INT )
RETURNS @Integers TABLE ( [IntValue] INT )
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @MinValue <= @MaxValue
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Integers ( [IntValue] ) VALUES ( @MinValue )
        SET @MinValue = @MinValue + 1
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

After that i use a inner join  like this:

```
use tempdb

select *into #test from 
(
    select 1 as n, 35 as periodId
    union 
    select 2 as n, 36 as periodId
    union 
    select 1 as n, 36 as periodId
    union 
    select 2 as n, 37 as periodId
) a

select p.* from #test   p
inner join  [dbo].[ufn_GenerateIntegers](36, 37) on [IntValue] = periodId
```

You could generate a String and then execute it but it is not very advised here, I think.

Comment: Sounds promising, but does SQL Server 2000 support table-valued functions? I am devving with SQL 2005, but deployment will be onto SQL 2000.

Comment: This works nicely on SQL 2005. Any idea if it will work on SQL 2000? BTW - the syntax of your inner join didn't work for me, I had to change it a bit.

Comment: I think it is possible in 2000 http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions but i can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if getPeriodsInRange is actually just a SQL query, you could just use a nested query instead of a procedure (you said simpler!):

```
Where P.PeriodID in (Select PeriodID from MyDateTable WHERE pd > SomeMinValue AND pd < SomeMaxValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a table-valued function that returns a one-column table with your Periods. Then you can inner-join this table-valued result. This way it should be executed only once, not for each row (but I'm not absolutely sure about this).

Further reading:
[Table-Valued User-Defined Functions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx)

Cheers
Matthias

Comment: If the SQL server is any good, the inner query will be optimized away anyhow.

Comment: Matthias - Does SQL Server 2000 support table-valued functions? I am devving with SQL 2005, but deployment will be onto SQL 2000. This is something that I think will work.

Comment: According to the Code Project article below it does. But I didn't think about a subquery when I wrote my answer - I think this might be simpler... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableValuedFnsAsArrays.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not "thinking in sets". The SQL language has but one data structure, being the table i.e. rows of columns. A column's data type must be scalar to satisfy first normal form. So there are no arrays, lists, etc.

While you could possibly generate a list of `PeriodID` values then squirt the list into a SQL query's text then use dynamic SQL capabilities to execute it, this isn't the way to go.

Consider your

```
Where P.PeriodID in (36, 37)
```

...can be rewritten as

```
Where P.PeriodID IN (
                     SELECT 36
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT 37
                    )
```

...or even

```
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT * 
                FROM (
                      SELECT 36
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT 37
                     ) AS DT1 (PeriodID)
               WHERE P.PeriodID = DT1.PeriodID
              );
```

...and you will hopefully be getting the idea of working with tables rather than lists of identifiers.

That said, taking a step back, this looks like a case where you are better off working with the natural key for periods, being the compound `(StartDate, EndDate)`, rather than the artifical/surrogate key `PeriodID`. Working with just the dates means you merely have to fnd the overlap e.g.

```
SELECT P1.PeriodID
  FROM Periods AS P1
 WHERE CASE 
          WHEN @StartDate > P1.StartDate THEN @StartDate 
          ELSE P1.StartDate
       END 
       <= 
       CASE 
          WHEN @EndDate > P1.EndDate THEN P1.EndDate 
          ELSE @EndDate 
       END;
```

Comment: You are right - I am not thinking in sets - I'm thinking more procedurally, and designed the solution using pseudo-procedural code on paper first. My SQL skills are pretty weak, I'm more of a C# developer. Thanks for the informative explanation though - I've learnt alot!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing in the GetPeriodsInRange function - cant you just pull that into the main query like...

```
Where P.PeriodID in
(
 select PeriodID from...etc
)
```

This wont work if the function is doing more complicated stuff! Maybe you can let us see what is in the function?